# KOTLIN - For loop argument is not support function - Looking for alternatives

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, arguments

The *code* below is for calculating exam results. **5** subject names and **5** points received from those subjects are recorded by the user in empty *arrays* created.

I have solved everything here. But I want to add **"th" "st" "rd" "nd"** after **"cycle"**. Which is written "**Please type lesson"** and **"Please type point"**

**For Example:**
"Please type **1st** point"

*But with my code I can:*
"Please type **1** point"

I tried to execute this process with the **"When"** condition, but I cannot because the loop argument **"cycle"** do not support the **last()** function

For example:

```
    when (cycle.last()) {
    1 ->  "st"
    2 -> "nd"
}
```

It will give me a result if worked **11st, 531st, 22nd, 232nd,** etc. That's I want

```
fun main() {

var subject = Array<String>(5){""}
var point = Array<Int>(5){0}


for (cycle in 0 until subject.count()) {

    println("Please type ${cycle+1} lesson")
    var typeLesson = readLine()!!.toString()
    subject[cycle] = typeLesson

    println("Please type ${cycle+1} point")
    var typePoint = readLine()!!.toInt()
    point[cycle] = typePoint
}


var sum = 0
for (cycle in 0 until point.count()) {
    println("${subject[cycle]} : ${point[cycle]}")

    sum = sum + point[cycle]/point.count()
}

println("Average point: $sum")
```

}

Comment: Do you realise it is `11th`, not `11st`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the number by 10 and get the remainder using `%`. That is the last digit.

```
fun Int.withOrdinalSuffix(): String =
    when (this % 10) {
        1 -> "${this}st"
        2 -> "${this}nd"
        3 -> "${this}rd"
        else -> "${this}th"
    }
```

Usage:

```
println("Please type ${(cycle+1).withOrdinalSuffix()} lesson")
```

Note that in English, 11, 12, 13 have the suffix "th", so you might want to do:

```
fun Int.withOrdinalSuffix(): String =
    if ((this % 100) in (11..13)) { // check last *two* digits first
        "${this}th"
    } else {
        when (this % 10) {
            1 -> "${this}st"
            2 -> "${this}nd"
            3 -> "${this}rd"
            else -> "${this}th"
        }
    }
```

instead.

Comment: Yeah, breaking this out into a separate function is the best idea I think - pass in a number, get back its ordinal form. It keeps things neat, and any complex logic is kept away from your main loop.

Comment: @cactustictacs Another advantage is that it can be reused from other code — useful for a simple, self-contained piece of functionality like this, especially as it's expressed as an extension function and hence relatively easy for an IDE to find.